# Python TSV File Parsing and UTF-8 Output Errors (TypeError: 'str' object is not callable)

Tags: python, utf-8, csv

I am having a

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

with this code (at line `outputfile.write(...)`). The input file is just a tsv file with some special characters but I have been able to work with it using the codecs library and I do not know what this error I am having is about.

```
import codecs
lines_seen = set() # holds lines already seen
inputfile = codecs.open('C:/Users/Allele&Lethality_Rows.txt',encoding='utf-8', mode='r')
outputfile = codecs.open('C:/Users/Removed_Poor_Partial_With.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='w')

if not "with" in inputfile or "poor" in inputfile or "partially" in inputfile:
    outputfile.write(inputfile.encoding('utf-8'))     
    outputfile.close()
```

Comment: It's crucial to say which line the error refers to, obviously.

Comment: Of Course, Sorry. This Line outputfile.write(inputfile.encoding('utf-8'))

Comment: added that piece of information to your question to be able to un-downvote you. I'd ask you to add things like these yourself, the next time.

Answer (score 0):

You did not read the files; `inputfile` is still a file object. On file objects opened by `codecs.open()` the `encoding` attribute is a *string*.

You need to read your file data:

```
with codecs.open('C:/Users/Allele&Lethality_Rows.txt',encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as infile:
    data = infile.read()

if not u"with" in data or u"poor" in data or u"partially" in data:
    with codecs.open('C:/Users/Removed_Poor_Partial_With.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='w') as outputfile:
        outputfile.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

`inputfile` is a `file` object that has a property, which is *not* a method. Thus you can't call it. Since I don't really know what you're trying to do, I can't help you do it right. Possibly you want to decode the contents of the file (`inputenc.read()` to read the whole contents into a `str`/`buffer` [depending on your Python version]), by using the `.decode('...')` string method.